# Ajax Not Working Right In Chrome/FireFox

Tags: javascript, ajax

This script I wrote works perfect on IE! It works on Chrome and FireFox the first time you do an action but it fails on the rest.

The script is simple. You can Add or Delete a user and each time you Add or Delete a user it updates the Updates the list.

```
function Add() {
  http_request = false;
  cache=Math.random();
  var username=document.getElementById('username').value;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
      http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
        http_request.overrideMimeType('text/html');
      }
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
      try {
        http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
        try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {}
      }
  }
  if (!http_request) {
      return false;
  }
  http_request.onreadystatechange=function(){ if (http_request.readyState==4 && http_request.status==200){ if (http_request.responseText=="OK"){ Update(); } else { document.getElementById('Response').innerHTML=http_request.responseText; } } }
  http_request.open('POST', 'add.php?username='+username+'&cache='+cache, true);
  http_request.send(null);
}

function Delete(username) {
  http_request = false;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
      http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
        http_request.overrideMimeType('text/html');
      }
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
      try {
        http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
        try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {}
      }
  }
  if (!http_request) {
      return false;
  }
  http_request.onreadystatechange=function(){ if (http_request.readyState==4 && http_request.status==200){ Update(); } }
  http_request.open('POST', 'delete.php?username='+username, true);
  http_request.send(null);
}

function Update() {
  http_request = false;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
      http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
        http_request.overrideMimeType('text/html');
      }
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
      try {
        http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
        try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {}
      }
  }
  if (!http_request) {
      return false;
  }
  http_request.onreadystatechange=function(){ if (http_request.readyState==4 && http_request.status==200){ document.getElementById("list").innerHTML=http_request.responseText; } }
  http_request.open('GET', 'list.php', true);
  http_request.send(null);
}
```

Please help and thank you

Comment: What is the error message? What do you mean by fails?

Comment: This is no error message. In IE you can ADD, DELETE users without any problems. In FireFox and Chrome you can ADD or DELETE 1 user and then when you try to ADD or DELETE a second user it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). You will have to write **much** less code and it will work in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks but I still would like to know the problem. Plus I don't feel like learning JQuery right now. :)

Comment: WOW! jQuery is AWESOME! I'll try to write it in jQuery now. Thank you all! :) But if someone does figure out the problem please post it.

Comment: I'm glad you've found it useful ;-)